# Why does 1.__add__(1) yield a syntax error?

Tags: python

Why does

```
1.__add__(1)
```

yield `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`? What do the extra brackets add?

```
(1).__add__(1)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an effect of the tokenizer:  `1.__add__(1)` is split into the tokens `"1."`, `"__add__"`, `"("`, `"1"`, and  `")"`, since the tokenizer always tries to built the longest possible token.  The first token is a floating point number, directly followed by an identifier, which is meaningless to the parser, so it throws a `SyntaxError`.

Simply adding a space before the dot will make this work:

```
>>> 1 .__add__(1)
2
```

Answer (score 8):

Because `1.` is a valid float literal, and the lexer follow the "maximum munch" rule - the longest match is used. After `1.` was consumed as float literal, the identifier `__add__` and parens follow. All the parser sees is `<float> <indentifier>` which is invalid (compare `1.0 __add__()`, which results in the same tokens and I hope you see how it's a syntax error) and meaningless. In the second example, there's an expression `1` wrapped in parens, *then* a dot (a single token, picked up by the parser as attribute access operator) etc. which is obviously valid.

Answer (score 2):

The parser expects to find a float, but `_` is not a valid digit. The parens tell the parser to stop parsing after the `1`.

Comment: Nope, `1..__add__(1)` returns a float, whereas the `(1).__add__(1)` returns an int.